# Calling Web-Service / Website from Java

Tags: java, web-services, gwt

Writing some additional classes for an existing GWT project. I need to:

- Request a URL
- Read in the webpage returned, in order to perform operations on.

The returned page is in very simple HTML, therefore parsing it shouldn't be very difficult, I just need to get the data first.

How do I do this in Java? What packages am I best looking at?

Comment: do you need this to happen on the client side, or on the server side?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With native Java API, the easiest way to read from an URL is using [`java.net.URL#openStream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URL.html#openStream()). Here's a basic example:

```java
try (InputStream response = new URL("https://www.stackoverflow.com").openStream()) {
    String body = new String(input.readAllBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    System.out.println(body);
}
```

You could feed the `InputStream` to any DOM/SAX parser of your taste. The average parser can take (in)directly an `InputStream` as argument or even a URL. [Jsoup is one of the better HTML parsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152138/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-the-leading-java-html-parsers/3154281#3154281).

In case you want a bit more control and/or want a more self-documenting API, then you can since Java 11 use the [`java.net.http.HttpClient`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpClient.html). It only gets verbose quickly when you merely want the response body:

```java
HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder().build();
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder().GET().uri(URI.create("https://stackoverflow.com")).build();
HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
String body = response.body();
System.out.println(body);
```

#### See also:

- [How to use java.net.URLConnection to fire and handle HTTP requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests)

Answer (score 1):

For HTML pages you should use [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/).

For Web services, you need a framework like [CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/).

Answer (score 0):

HttpClient, although very good, is considered obsolete.
[HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/) is an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something like this on the client, take a look at the [HTTP types of GWT](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/1.6/DevGuideServerCommunication.html#DevGuideHttpRequests). But be aware that you are subject to the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) then.