# how to parse html

Tags: java, html-parser

I have downloaded the Java [HtmlParser](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/) but I dont know how to use the API  for extracting the HTML data. Can you give some example so that I can work on it?

Comment: Please start by stating *which* java html parser you are using.

Comment: Which HTML Parser you downloaded?

Comment: Are you talking about *this* parser: http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/ They have a "Samples" page: maybe what you're looking for is there: http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/samples.html

Comment: There are infinitely many possible examples, so this question could have infinitely many correct answers. This question is therefore _Too Broad_. What **precisely** do you not understand about how to use the API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're talking about [HtmlParser](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/)? Rather pick a parser with less verbose API like [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/). All you need to learn are then [CSS selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/) which are already obvious enough to the average frontend developer.

Here's a kickoff example which displays your current question and the names of all answerers:

```
package com.stackoverflow.q3416036;

import java.net.URL;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL url = new URL("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3416036");
        Document document = Jsoup.parse(url, 3000);

        String question = document.select("#question .post-text").text();
        System.out.println("Question: " + question);

        Elements answerers = document.select("#answers .user-details a");
        for (Element answerer : answerers) {
            System.out.println("Answerer: " + answerer.text());
        }
    }

}
```

#### See also:

- [Pros and cons of HTML parsers in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152138/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-the-leading-java-html-parsers/3154281#3154281)