# Get website description using Google search

Tags: java, url, search

is it possible get site description using google engine search for a specific link?

For example I would send this input:

> http://www.facebook.com

and get this output:

> Facebook is a social utility that connects people with friends and others who work, study and live around them. People use Facebook to keep up with friends, ...

How I can do it?

EDIT: I solve my problem, but if I would get category of url from google (for example, Facebook - Social Network), there is a way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can you search Google Programmatically Java API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727662/how-can-you-search-google-programmatically-java-api)

Comment: you can try YQL (http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/ or http://tinyurl.com/66uhsve) also, 

`select * from html where url='http://www.yahoo.com' and xpath='//meta[@name="description"]'`

Comment: Thanks Marcog, it's a duplicate, but now I change my question description.