# Google search via Java Api - Multiple requests

Tags: java, google-search-api

I'm coming from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727662/how-can-you-search-google-programmatically-java-api).

The following code does not work well:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        String google = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=";
        String search = "test";
        String charset = "UTF-8";

        URL url = new URL(google + URLEncoder.encode(search, charset));
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), charset);
        GoogleResults results = new Gson().fromJson(reader, GoogleResults.class);

        // Show title and URL of 1st result.
        System.out.println(results.getResponseData().getResults().get(0).getTitle());
        System.out.println(results.getResponseData().getResults().get(0).getUrl());
    }
}
```

The search query works fine if I run it one time, however in this loop I get a null pointer exception.

Unfortunately I need my program to make several queries :( What can I do?

It returns a `NullPointerException` at the first `results.getResponseData`.

Comment: i am also facing this problem. So how to get rid of that?

Comment: you can't. It's against Google's TOS. You could try adding a longer delay though, or try sending IPs to Google.

Comment: i have added ip also. but still not working.
`String address = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&start=0&userip=14.90.136.150&safe=active&rsz=8&q=";`

sometime it do't give any exception and search the text from google but most of the time it throws `NullPointerException`. why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because Google actively blocks suspected terms of service abuse.  See section 5.3 here:

http://www.google.com/accounts/TOS

If Google detects that you are issuing search requests via a program without their consent, they don't send back results.  Your JSON response will contain this:

```
{"responseData": null, "responseDetails": "Suspected Terms of Service Abuse. Please see http://code.google.com/apis/errors", "responseStatus": 403}
```

Comment: But sometime it do't give any exception and search the text from google and sometime it throws NullPointerException. why?

Answer (score 0):

**Check to make sure `results` and other contained objects are not `null` before you use them.**

```
if ((results != null) && (results.getResponseData() != null) &&
    (results.getResponseData().getResults() != null) &&
    (results.getResponseData().getResults().get(0) != null)) {
    // Show title and URL of 1st result.
    System.out.println(results.getResponseData().getResults().get(0).getTitle());
    System.out.println(results.getResponseData().getResults().get(0).getUrl());
}
```

Comment: Well and good. What I'm asking is - why is results NULL in the first place? And how can I avoid it.