# Make program running a web site for different inputs

Tags: java, php, python, html

This is a general question, and I don't expect any specific solution here. I'm just very curious about the approach.

Let us say I have txt-file with many keywords. There are so many keywords that I can't make a seperate google-search for each one of them. That would take too long time. My goal is to make a program which takes every keyword in the file, makes a google-search for that keyword, then saves the result in a file (e.g. a line at the result page), then proceeds to the next keyword and does the exact same procedure.

I wonder if this is possible at all? What kind of programming language should I use? what would be the approach?

Comment: The first thing is that massive automated script is not allowed from nearly all sites for example google https://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html doesn't allow more than 100 request per day per user from a computer program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a job for a scripting language.  You could go with wget in a shell script, perl/python etc, or you could look into the [api google provides](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html).

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way of doing it.

1. Create a java(or any other language) program which will read the file with keywords.
2. For each keyword read from the file, Use Google Search APIs to search ([See example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727662/how-can-you-search-google-programmatically-java-api)).
3. Save the the results returned from API in a file.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for something like bowser automation I suppose. You can look for [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) and choose python as your tool.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this would be possible.

Pretty much any programming language you like would do this.  I will assume, from your question, that you are new to programming, so I might recommend VB.NET, as the syntax is pretty simple.

You can form your own URLs using parameters, like http://www.google.com/search?as_q=nintendo+wii&as_sitesearch=.com.  A Google search for Google Search URL parameters might be a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

Taking account the limitation of google api that is possible. I think the best tool for it is python.