# how do save image from google images using google API?

Tags: java, image, google-image-search

i'm trying to search in Google-images some different and save the first result for every query with java Google API.

I managed to search in Google and get the json object which contains the search results. the object contains the web sites which contains the images,and not the image address

code:

```
URL url = new URL("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?" +
                    "v=1.0&q="+properties.getProperty(Integer.toString(i))+"&userip=IP");
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            connection.addRequestProperty("Referer", "images.google.com");

        String line;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        builder.append(line);
        }

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(builder.toString())
```

I'm also know how to save image if i had the image link.

my problem is how to get the first (or second or whatever) image right address and not the web address (example www.yadayadayada.com/image.png)

10x

Answer (score 10, accepted):

JSON interface is described at [JSON Developer's Guide](https://developers.google.com/image-search/v1/jsondevguide). In particular, [JSON reference](https://developers.google.com/image-search/v1/jsondevguide#json_reference) section outlines response format and guaranteed fields. You can use a value of `url` property.

Given the URL, you can read the image and write it to the disk using [ImageIO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html). Here is the relevant [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/index.html).

If the image manipulation and presentation is not required, then you could use [HttpURLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) to simply download the file.

EDIT: example

Below is a simple example based on the code included in the question. It performs a search and displays the first image.

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class TestImage {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            URL url = new URL("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=Godfather");
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

            String line;
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line);
            }

            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(builder.toString());
            String imageUrl = json.getJSONObject("responseData").getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(0).getString("url");

            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new URL(imageUrl));
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "", "", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, new ImageIcon(image));
        } catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage(), "Failure", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey,
thank you for your answer but my problem is I get in the url fields the sites which contains the image and not the link to the image itself.
example: if i search The Godfather i get http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0068646/

Comment: @user1383845 please see if my edit can help you. I included a tiny sample that makes a search and displays the first image.

Comment: google search has been deprecated, is there any alternative to that ? thanks.

Comment: @MajidL There is [Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview) that supports image search.

Comment: @Aqua thank you. I came across this library but I thought it was used to search in a list of specific websites using a custom search engine, is it possible not to restrict the search ?

Comment: @MajidL Hmm, true. But looks like there is a trick to enable *Google Custom Search* to search the entire web. See this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11206266/1048330).

Comment: @Aqua Thank you very much. I managed to add wildcard domains like `*.com` and `*.org` etc... That shoud do it for now.

Comment: @Aqua Thank you. I came across your solution and it helps me a lot. However, I tried to modify the code to try and print out every image's url returned by the search but it seems that it will only return 3 urls at most. Why is that so?

Comment: @jl90 you're welcome! :) may be it is due to the [deprecation](https://developers.google.com/image-search/) of this API, see comments above for more details.

Comment: @Aqua Do you have a working Java version that involves the new API?

Comment: @MikeWarren unfortunately no, see if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10257276/1048330) is helpful, also explore [google-custom-search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-custom-search) tag.

Comment: Did you see my comment on there?

Comment: @MikeWarren There are limitations, see [pricing](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview#Pricing) for details.

Comment: Also, given what I am trying to do, which is outlined here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26393873/searching-google-images-from-java , what type of API key would I have to obtain???

Comment: Can anyone tell me where is JSONObject class