# Searching image with its description on google

Tags: java, image, search, google-custom-search

I have successfully created an **API key** for using **Google Custom Search Api**,The task now I want to perform is to upload some image from my hard drive and get the results from the website I have specified while getting my API key from Google console(from control panel).I have tried the code from [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257276/java-code-for-using-google-custom-search-api) question asked on stackoverflow(code also given below)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String key="YOUR KEY";
    String qry="Android";
    URL url = new URL(
            "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key="+key+ "&cx=013036536707430787589:_pqjad5hr1a&q="+ qry + "&alt=json");
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            (conn.getInputStream())));

    String output;
    System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
    while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {

        if(output.contains("\"link\": \"")){                
            String link=output.substring(output.indexOf("\"link\": \"")+("\"link\": \"").length(), output.indexOf("\","));
            System.out.println(link);       //Will print the google search links
        }     
    }
    conn.disconnect();                              
}
```

Now how can I search my image and get the results. **And also while searching,this piece of code is searching the whole Google , but I want it to search only the websites I have specified in the control  panel at the google console while creating API KEY**.