# How to Implement Google Search in Android SearchView

Tags: android, json, searchview

What would be the proper way to Implement a Google Search with SearchView. For example, I press the Search button, and enter a query, and then after I hit enter button, it would do a google search in which I can get JSON data. All the examples I've seen are with lists or something similar. I'm trying figure out how to implement a Web search into SearchView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! It was probably something to do with my Android Manifest or something:

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.alexoladele.testingshit">

    <!-- Permissions's -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
            android:value=".SearchActivity" />

        <!-- Main Activity -->
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- SearchActivity -->
        <activity
            android:name=".SearchActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

SearchActivity.java:

```
package com.alexoladele.testingshit;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.google.api.services.customsearch.Customsearch;


public class SearchActivity extends ListActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "SearchActivity";
    private String qry;
    private Customsearch customsearch;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate: ContentView was set to activity_search");

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate: Got Intent");

        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate: Handling Intent!");
        handleIntent(intent);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        setIntent(intent);
        handleIntent(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // Call detail activity for clicked entry
    }

    private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            qry = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            Log.i(TAG, "handleIntent: QUERY: " + qry + "\n Starting the doSearch Method!");
            doSearch(qry);
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "handleIntent: Intent WAS NOT search");
        }
    }

    private void doSearch(String query) {
        Log.i(TAG, "doSearch: In doSearch Method!");
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.alexoladele.testingshit;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

import layout.WelcomeScreenFragment;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    SearchView searchView;

    final static String[] NEEDED_PERMISSIONS = {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.INTERNET,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE};


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
//        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 0);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), NEEDED_PERMISSIONS[0])
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), NEEDED_PERMISSIONS[1])
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), NEEDED_PERMISSIONS[2])
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, NEEDED_PERMISSIONS, 808);
            Log.i(TAG, "onCreate: Requesting Permissions");

        }

//        Makes sure that the root_layout view is not null before doing anything
        if (findViewById(R.id.root_layout) != null) {

//            Makes sure that there's no saved instance before proceeding
            if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction manager = fm.beginTransaction();
                manager
                        .add(R.id.root_layout, WelcomeScreenFragment.newInstance(), "welcomeScreen")
                        .commit();
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (808) {
            case 808:
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permissions GRANTED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permissions NOT GRANTED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);

//        VARIBLES TO USE
        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
        searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);

//      Set Up the search Function
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                return false;
            }
        });

        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);

        ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), SearchActivity.class);
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(componentName));
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Pang haha not anymore!

Comment: (1) The revision history is public; anyone can see this answer as it was at any time. Your keys are still visible there. (2) To permanently get rid of them, flag for mod-- oh, dammit, you don't have flag privileges yet. Well, I flagged the posts for a mod to take a look and wipe the secret info.

Answer (score 1):

try using [Google Custom Search api](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview)

Comment: Yeah I plan on using that, but I'm really looking for examples of doing it, because I can't seem to find any

Comment: check https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/introduction#try_it

Comment: Thanks, but Is there a code example of how to implement it in Android?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257276/java-code-for-using-google-custom-search-api

Comment: The issue is that I'm not really understanding how to go from tapping on the search icon and inputting a query, to actually performing the search. When I do so, it just shows a blank screen

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but you should not put your `SearchView searchView` as a global variable, as that can lead to memory leaks. Instead, keep it as a local variable inside of `onCreateOptionsMenu`.