# How can I get all the results with searching Google Programmatically Java API?

Tags: java

I read this question and answers.

[How can you search Google Programmatically Java API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727662/how-can-you-search-google-programmatically-java-api)

When I run the codes in the answer and search anything, it returns only 4 results from google.

How can I get all the results?

Answer (score 1):

Did you read the documentation available from Google?

The API described in that answer is being deprecated and has the number of queries you may do reduced.

The alternative is here:

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview

Answer (score 1):

The post is a bit old but in case someone else is asking the question. I've found this website that explains what to do to send a request on google search engines.

http://www.basicsbehind.com/google-search-programmatically/