# how to extract URLs from google search results using Java

Tags: java, parsing

I have asked this question previously and the question closed as it has been previously asked and well answered in the following: [How can you search Google Programmatically Java API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727662/how-can-you-search-google-programmatically-java-api)

Unfortunately, "The Google Web Search API has been officially deprecated as of November 1, 2010". So, can any one please provide me with an answer for my question. I need to extract URLs from google search results and save them to txt file without duplicate results. I was able to extract URLs from web page using JSoup, but not google search results.

Comment: Google web search API was deprecated, and this took it's place: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview

Comment: Please, show us some effort. Surely the problem consists mainly in retrieving/parsing google data. Or is the "save them to txt file without duplicate results" also part of the question? It is better to break the problem into small issues concerning only one domain or field instead of just asking an abrangent question. This makes the question seem as though it lacks some clarification.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can get the link information via  [JSON](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/using_rest)(javascript object notation)   and then use [this to get the json in java](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)