# know the page rank for certain key words

Tags: seo, pagerank

I want to know the page rank for certain key words against my page. For example I wrote "best movies 2012"  my page does come, but in 30th to 50th page. I want to query in the result set Google gave against my keywords so that I can see the rank of my page and my competitors against typical keywords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may be confusing PageRank with positions. PageRank is an algorithm that Google uses to determine the authority of your site. This doesn't always affect the positions of certain keywords.

There are plenty of good programs and web services around that you can use such as

```
http://raventools.com/
```

Most of the good free web services have been closed down due to Google now limiting the amount of searches performed and charging for this data.

You could check out:

```
http://www.semrush.com
```

It's free but you have to register to get data.

Answer (score 0):

There are several web services providing this functionality: http://raventools.com/ or http://seomoz.org/

Or, you can perform the task manually. Here is an example on how to query google search using Java: [How can you search Google Programmatically Java API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727662/how-can-you-search-google-programmatically-java-api)

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare your webpage PageRank **and** website PR against those of the competition. The best indication we have of website PR is the HomePage PagRank.
Ensure that you do this for the appropriate Google domain - USA - Google.com - UK Google.co.uk etc
The technique is described in more detail on http://www.keywordseopro.com
You can repeat the technique for each keyword.