# search google and get results using java swing

Tags: java, swing, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can you search Google Programmatically Java API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727662/how-can-you-search-google-programmatically-java-api)

I want to get search string from the user in a JTextfield and search it in google and get results and display it in my application... Can anyone tell how to search google from my desktop application... I am new to java

Comment: how to search google search using java api: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727662/how-can-you-search-google-programmatically-java-api

Comment: how to use tables in swing (to display result data): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html