# easiest (legal) way to programmatically get the google search result count?

Tags: java, google-search

I want to get the estimated result count for certain Google search engine queries (on the whole web) using Java code.

I need to do only very few queries per day, so at first [Google Web Search API](https://developers.google.com/web-search/), though deprecated, seemed good enough (see e.g. [How can you search Google Programmatically Java API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727662/how-can-you-search-google-programmatically-java-api)). But as it turned out, the numbers returned by this API are very different from those returned by www.google.com (see e.g. http://code.google.com/p/google-ajax-apis/issues/detail?id=32). So these numbers are pretty useless for me.

I also tried [Google Custom Search engine](https://www.google.com/cse/), which exhibits the same problem.

What do you think is the simplest solution for my task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/**** @author RAJESH Kharche */
//open Netbeans
//Choose Java->prject
//name it GoogleSearchAPP

package googlesearchapp;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class GoogleSearchAPP {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // TODO code application logic here

            final int Result;

            Scanner s1=new Scanner(System.in);
            String Str;
            System.out.println("Enter Query to search: ");//get the query to search
            Str=s1.next();
            Result=getResultsCount(Str);

            System.out.println("Results:"+ Result);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(GoogleSearchAPP.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }      
    }

    private static int getResultsCount(final String query) throws IOException {
        final URL url;
        url = new URL("https://www.google.com/search?q=" + URLEncoder.encode(query, "UTF-8"));
        final URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

        connection.setConnectTimeout(60000);
        connection.setReadTimeout(60000);
        connection.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Google Chrome/36");//put the browser name/version

        final Scanner reader = new Scanner(connection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");  //scanning a buffer from object returned by http request

        while(reader.hasNextLine()){   //for each line in buffer
            final String line = reader.nextLine();

            if(!line.contains("\"resultStats\">"))//line by line scanning for "resultstats" field because we want to extract number after it
                continue;

            try{        
                return Integer.parseInt(line.split("\"resultStats\">")[1].split("<")[0].replaceAll("[^\\d]", ""));//finally extract the number convert from string to integer
            }finally{
                reader.close();
            }
        }
        reader.close();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please add some explanation to your solution?

Comment: hey if you want me to sent you the content returned by [link](https://www.google.com/search?q=) in the object i surely will.

Comment: You seem to have reused the code from the answer by @JoshM. However, you have modified and extended the code. What was the reason to do so? What does your code better/differently than that of @JoshM? Such kind of explanation would help readers to understand your solution.

Comment: I just tried Josh's code, didn't work.   Tried Rajesh's class and it did.

Comment: @DavidH.Bennett Any reason why the difference?

Comment: @RobertoBonini  it was a q&d count I needed I didn't investigate :)

Comment: It's not legal, I think it's a violation of Google TOS.

Answer (score 3):

Well something you can do is perform an actual Google search programmatically to begin with. The easiest possible way to do this would be to access the url https://www.google.com/search?q=QUERY_HERE and then you want to scrape the result count off that page.

Here is a quick example of how to do that:

```
    private static int getResultsCount(final String query) throws IOException {
    final URL url = new URL("https://www.google.com/search?q=" + URLEncoder.encode(query, "UTF-8"));
    final URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    connection.setConnectTimeout(60000);
    connection.setReadTimeout(60000);
    connection.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
    final Scanner reader = new Scanner(connection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
    while(reader.hasNextLine()){
        final String line = reader.nextLine();
        if(!line.contains("<div id=\"resultStats\">"))
            continue;
        try{
            return Integer.parseInt(line.split("<div id=\"resultStats\">")[1].split("<")[0].replaceAll("[^\\d]", ""));
        }finally{
            reader.close();
        }
    }
    reader.close();
    return 0;
}
```

For usage, you would do something like:

```
final int count = getResultsCount("horses");
System.out.println("Estimated number of results for horses: " + count);
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks good. But AFAIR the terms of service do not permit this. Do they? They say something like one must use only Google GUIs and/or APIs …

Comment: Surely that might be the case, but I think it depends on what your intent is. I'm not too sure if this is breaching any of their terms or not, but I think you should probably look into it to make sure it is safe.

Comment: FYI. This approach eventually leads to a 503 Error and a captcha.