# Google Search Result count in Unity c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, httpwebrequest, google-search, web-search

So i want to retrieve the amount of results from a google search. I dont use the Google search API because it doesnt give the right numbers, i want the exact same that are one the webpage when you google someting (thats actually the whole point of the game). I tried Python (with no experience) but failed misaberly. Then I search a bit around the Internet and this what i came up with:
(found code but it was in javascript, and im also to dumb for that)
Edit: Heres the link to the JavaScript [r google search result count retrieve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30199157/r-google-search-result-count-retrieve)
And apparently some guy wanted the same but in java, so if someone could "translate" this([easiest (legal) way to programmatically get the google search result count?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18204814/easiest-legal-way-to-programmatically-get-the-google-search-result-count)) I would be really happy

```
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using UnityEngine.Windows;
using File = System.IO.File;

public class SearchGoogle : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string keyword;
    private string searchwebsite;
    string fileName = "MyFile.html";

    void Start()
    {
        searchwebsite = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + keyword;
        Debug.Log(searchwebsite);
        StartCoroutine(GetText());
        Debug.Log("Coroutine wird gecallt");
    }

    IEnumerator GetText()
    {
        UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(searchwebsite);
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();

        if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
        {
            Debug.Log("Fehler:(");
            Debug.Log(www.error);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("CErfolg");
            // Show results as text
            Debug.Log(www.downloadHandler.text);

            if (File.Exists(fileName))
            {
                Debug.Log(fileName + " already exists.");
            }
            var sr = File.CreateText(fileName);
            sr.WriteLine(www.downloadHandler.text);
            sr.Close();

            //Printing it in a file to open it in my browser, not nessecary in the final build



            // Or retrieve results as binary data
            byte[] results = www.downloadHandler.data;
        }
    }
}
```

But this code just returns the scource code of the website, and I actually dont quite understand it. Does anyone have a solution for this (i just want the amount of results, nothing else)? I just think it would be possible to do, but if it's not, correct me please. Thanks in advace. 
Edit:(The div in html is called "result-stats"

Comment: A webpage is a HTML file on the server which is text and you are using File.CreateText(fileName);.

Comment: Could you post a link to the JavaScript you found? Some people might be able to utilize that to help you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30199157/r-google-search-result-count-retrieve