# How to extract links from Google HTML result page?

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

I am reading a text file that contains HTML code from Google search results. Then I parse it and I try to extract the links with this code:

```
FileReader in = new FileReader("A.txt");
BufferedReader p = new BufferedReader(in);
while(p.readLine() != null)
{
  String html = p.readLine();
  Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
  Elements Link = doc.select("a[href");
  for(Element element :Link)
  {   
    if(element != null)
    {
       System.out.println(element);
    }
  }
}
```

But I got many non-link strings. How can I show the links, not anything else?

Comment: According to this [question][1] what your asking is against google TOS

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727662/how-can-you-search-google-programmatically-java-api

Comment: can you post the html code you're trying to parse? Because google search result page does not contain your results as direct HTML anchors

Comment: exactly i have this problem,the google search result HTML is difrrent

Answer (score 0):

Please try again with a complete selector, not only "a[href":

`Elements links = doc.select("a[href]"); // a with href`

See the [Selector](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html) document for the full support - especially the examples on the right side.

Comment: If the links are in an iframe, you need to select that first. doc.select("iframe") will help you.