# Extracting Search Results

Tags: java, search

I am really new to java programming. I am writting a program/app to query yahoo,bing and hotbot at once with a keyword given by the user. I want to display the results URLs altogether in one page. But i could only send queries and save the resulting html code in a notepad file. There is a lot of rubbish in the html document alongwith advertisements. How do i obtain only the resulting urls from search results and display them ??

i hav done this much :

```
package linker;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Linker {
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {

       URL url = new URL("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/India");
       HttpURLConnection connect = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
       BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                            connect.getInputStream()));
       String inputLine;

       while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
       {

           System.out.println(inputLine);
           in.close();
       }
       BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
       new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
       BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("outputfile.txt"));
       String inputLine;
       while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
             try{
                   writer.write(inputLine);
                }
       catch(IOException e){
                   e.printStackTrace();
                   return;
        }
        }
        in.close();
        writer.close();
        String inputline;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader (newFile("out.txt")));                  
        while ((inputline = br.readLine()) != null)  
        {
          System.out.println(inputline);
        }
       }
       }package linker;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Linker {
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {

       URL url = new URL("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/India");
       HttpURLConnection connect = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
       BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                            connect.getInputStream()));
       String inputLine;

       while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
       {

           System.out.println(inputLine);
           in.close();
       }
       BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
       new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
       BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("outputfile.txt"));
       String inputLine;
       while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
             try{
                   writer.write(inputLine);
                }
       catch(IOException e){
                   e.printStackTrace();
                   return;
        }
        }
        in.close();
        writer.close();
        String inputline;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader (newFile("out.txt")));                  
        while ((inputline = br.readLine()) != null)  
        {
          System.out.println(inputline);
        }
       }
       }package linker;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Linker {
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {

       URL url = new URL("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/India");
       HttpURLConnection connect = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
       BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                            connect.getInputStream()));
       String inputLine;

       while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
       {

           System.out.println(inputLine);
           in.close();
       }
       BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
       new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
       BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("outputfile.txt"));
       String inputLine;
       while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
             try{
                   writer.write(inputLine);
                }
       catch(IOException e){
                   e.printStackTrace();
                   return;
        }
        }
        in.close();
        writer.close();
        String inputline;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader (newFile("out.txt")));                  
        while ((inputline = br.readLine()) != null)  
        {
          System.out.println(inputline);
        }
       }
       }package linker;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Linker {
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {

       URL url = new URL("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/India");
       HttpURLConnection connect = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
       BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                            connect.getInputStream()));
       String inputLine;

       while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
       {

           System.out.println(inputLine);
           in.close();
       }
       BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
       new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
       BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("outputfile.txt"));
       String inputLine;
       while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
             try{
                   writer.write(inputLine);
                }
       catch(IOException e){
                   e.printStackTrace();
                   return;
        }
        }
        in.close();
        writer.close();
        String inputline;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader (newFile("out.txt")));                  
        while ((inputline = br.readLine()) != null)  
        {
          System.out.println(inputline);
        }
       }
       }
```

Comment: most sites have specific APIs you can use to get search results back.  That would be more efficient than trying to page-scrape.

Comment: for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727662/how-can-you-search-google-programmatically-java-api