# What are those ".g>.r>a"

Tags: jsoup

I am following a tutorial given in the following link

[How can you search Google Programmatically Java API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727662/how-can-you-search-google-programmatically-java-api)

please refer the top answer, when I try that I get 0 links in my page and if I replace that `.g>.r>a` with a `*`, I'm getting some links so the question here is that what does they mean.

I have already looked into JSOUP api reference but i do not understand the way they have explained that.

Comment: This is css selector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the signification of the CSS selector:

```
.g    /* Select any element (1) with class called 'g' */
> .r  /* Select any direct child elements (2) of (1) with class called 'r' */
> a   /* Select any anchor element directly under (2) */
```