# How can I get the first URL result on Google Video Search? (tag selector)

Tags: java, html, tags, jsoup

I want to get the first URL result google video search programmatically using JSoup. I have a problem with Google video encoding or Html tags.(Probably HTML tag: .g>.r>a)

```
public static String getYoutubeURLByName(String search) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, MalformedURLException, MalformedURLException, MalformedURLException, MalformedURLException, IOException {
    String google = "https://www.google.com/videohp?hl=";
    String charset = "UTF-8";
    String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0"; 
    Elements links = Jsoup.connect(google + URLEncoder.encode(search, charset)).userAgent(userAgent).get().select(".g>.r>a");
    String url = links.get(0).absUrl("href");
    url = URLDecoder.decode(url.substring(url.indexOf('=') + 1, url.indexOf('&')), "UTF-8");
    return url;
}
```

I get the following error. I think that Jsoup.connect can't add Element on array list because of something is wrong with encoding url or html tag. (Probably html tag, my poor html :( )

> at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:657)
>   at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:433)
>   at getYoutubeURLByName(.java:100)

Not possible duplicate of: [How can you search Google Programmatically Java API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727662/how-can-you-search-google-programmatically-java-api)

Important Edit:
And string google should be:

```
https://www.google.com/search?tbm=vid&hl=en-TR&source=hp&biw=&bih=&q=
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your selector is not correct, because elements are not direct childs, try using:

```
Elements links = Jsoup.connect(google + URLEncoder.encode(search, charset)).userAgent(userAgent).get().select(".g .r a");
```