# How to get image src using regular expression

Tags: html, regex

I have following HTML markup,

```
<div id="subcontent_l">
    <p>
        <a href="/membership-packages/"><img height="202" width="644" alt="" src="http://74.52.72.231/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/banner1.jpg" title="banner1" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-299">
        </a>
    </p>
    <p class="subc">Access to Guaranteed Healthcare Benefits</p>
    <p><a href="http://74.52.72.231/join-now"><img height="37" width="166" alt="" src="http://74.52.72.231/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/jn2.jpg" title="jn" class="alignleft size-full wp-image-229"></a></p>
</div>
```

Now on the above markup I want to find that anchor which have following image with src=jn2.jpg
After finding this my Markup should be like this

Desired result would be:-

```
<a href="http://74.52.72.231/join-now"><img height="37" width="166" alt="" src="http://74.52.72.231/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/jn2.jpg" title="jn" class="alignleft size-full wp-image-229"></a>
```

I want to do this using regular expression, I have a regular expression which find a all the images tag inside .
my expression is `/[^<]*<a.*href[\s]*=[\s]*("[^"]*").*[\s]*<img.*\/a>$`
But not able to find the same what i want.
Please help me.

Comment: Don't parse XML or HTML with Regexes, just use an XML parser ;)

Comment: Mandatory link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: -1 for the reasons stated above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regex is unsuitable for this job. HTML is not a regular language. Rather use a HTML parser. Every self-respected programming language offers HTML parsing facilities and/or libraries. I have no idea what programming language you're using, but if you're familiar with Java, I'd recommend [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org) for this. Here's an example which does what you want:

```
String html = "<div id=\"subcontent_l\">"
    + "<p>"
    + "<a href=\"/membership-packages/\"><img height=\"202\" width=\"644\" alt=\"\" src=\"http://74.52.72.231/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/banner1.jpg\" title=\"banner1\" class=\"aligncenter size-full wp-image-299\">"
    + "</a>"
    + "</p>"
    + "<p class=\"subc\">Access to Guaranteed Healthcare Benefits</p>"
    + "<p><a href=\"http://74.52.72.231/join-now\"><img height=\"37\" width=\"166\" alt=\"\" src=\"http://74.52.72.231/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/jn2.jpg\" title=\"jn\" class=\"alignleft size-full wp-image-229\"></a></p>"
    + "</div>";

Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
Element link = document.select("img[src$=jn2.jpg]").first().parent();
System.out.println(link.outerHtml()); // Prints the desired result.
```

Jsoup uses [jQuery](http://jquery.com)-like [CSS selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html) to select elements of interest. For C#/.NET there's a Jsoup port: [NSoup](http://nsoup.codeplex.com/). Also PHP has a similar library: [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/).

#### See also:

- [Parsing HTML the Cthulhu way](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html)
- [Pros and cons of HTML parsers in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152138/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-the-leading-java-html-parsers)

Answer (score -1):

What Colin Hebert says is true but still there is a regex

```
preg_match_all('%<a[^>]*href=(\'|")(.+?)\1[^>]*?>.*?<img[^>]*src=(\'|")(.+?)\1[^>]*?>.*?</a>%si', $code, $result, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```