# HTML processing in Java: Convert HTML to other formats

Tags: java, html-parsing

OK, there are many HTML/XML parsers for Java. What I want to do is a bit more than just knowing how to parse it. I want to filter the content and have it in suitable form.

More precisely, I want to keep only the text and images. However, I want to preserve some of the text formatting, too, like: italic, bold, alignment, etc.

All this is for the reason that I'm trying to implement a converter that converts html to a specific format that I've created myself for my own purposes.

Any ideas? Surely, it must have been done many times before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O.K. I think found it out: when parsing the `Element` I can construct a `javax.swing.text.html.InlineView`, i.e. `InlineElement ie = new InlineView(element)` and then get the attributes as `ie.getAttributes)`.

Right. If you could help more, i.e. have some first-hand experience to share, please do!

Answer (score 5):

If your intent is to clean user-submitted content against a safe white-list to prevent XSS, then I'd suggest to use [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org) for this. [It provides a builtin white-list](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/cleaning-html/whitelist-sanitizer). It's then as simple as:

```
String safeHtml = Jsoup.clean(unsafeHtml, Whitelist.basicWithImages());
```

You can customize the `Whitelist` as described in its [javadoc](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/safety/Whitelist.html).

#### See also:

- [Pros and cons of HTML parsers in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152138/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-the-leading-java-html-parsers)

Comment: Damn, this JSoup is really well thought. +1

Comment: Thanks. The link turned out to be ***very*** useful! As I *said* I am trying to convert HTML to my custom format. Jsoup is quite promising, but HtmlUnit *is* quite close to the point! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome :) After cleaning you could use Jsoup as well to iterate over all HTML elements and convert/transform each into another markup. You can also do this with XSLT, it may only end up to be pretty complex since you've to specify every HTML element and/or attribute separately.

Answer (score 2):

[JTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/) + XSLT?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [HTML Parser](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/), it could be handy.

Answer (score 0):

you can use xml dom parser under packages org.w3c.dom and javax.xml with that you can easily parse the document and get the node contents

```
 Document doc = DocumentBuilder.parse(file);
```

and then get the elements by using

```
NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("p"); // for paragraph tags
```

and then get the content from nodelist, it'll give u whole content in paragraph tag, like that you can apply for any tag