# jTidy and TagSoup documentation

Tags: java, jtidy, tag-soup, jericho-html-parser

I'm looking for documentation (officially documentation if it is possible) for TagSoup and jTidy libraries.

I want use this libraries to manipulate html "tagsoup" files that include xml tags with different namespaces mixed between html (html, xhtml or html5) tags.

I have tested HTMLCleaner, NekoHTML and Jericho, but i don't find documentation for jTidy and TagSoup, apart from simplest examples to clear a file.

I need documentation about manipulate contents, replace tags, extract info, etc...

Thanks

Note:
After test all options, I used **StAX** / **Woodstox** :

- http://wiki.fasterxml.com/WoodstoxHome
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StAX
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/stax/using.html

Comment: Did you consider [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org)? It can't be done [better/easier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152138/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-the-leading-java-html-parsers). It has a good [Cookbook](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/) as well.

Comment: I'm testing Jsoup. She look easy but view examples code, it seem no thread-safe. am i right?

Comment: Is it me or does Jsoup not support output stream ?

Comment: @slott Check at the end of the question. StAX is for streams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to a similar question on the tagsoup-friends google group may help:

[Documentation for TagSoup](http://groups.google.com/group/tagsoup-friends/browse_thread/thread/636a80dbd08ce27e)

You've probably already seen them, but the javadoc for JTidy is available here: http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/apidocs/index.html

Comment: So TagSoup use SAX API, but ¿JTidy? :( Thanks

Comment: JTidy does not, it is basically something like you give it an input stream, get it parsed and then get the output from the output stream.