# JSP Page Crawler that extracts all input parameters

Tags: java, jsp, web-crawler, web-scraping

Do you happen to know of an opensource Java component that provides the facility to scan a set of dynamic pages (JSP) and then extract all the input parameters from there. Of course, a crawler would be able to crawl static code and not dynamic code, but my idea here is to extend it to crawl a webserver including all the server-side code. Naturally, I am assuming that the tool will have full access to the crawled webserver and not by using any hacks.

The idea is to build a static analyzer that has the capacity to detect all parameters (request.getParameter() and such) fields from all dynamic pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The idea is to build a static analyzer that has the capacity to detect all parameter fields from all dynamic pages.

You cannot use a **web** crawler (basically, a HTML parser) to extract request parameters. They can at highest scan the HTML structure. You can use for example [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) for this:

```
for (Element form : Jsoup.connect("http://google.com").get().select("form")) {
    System.out.printf("Form found: action=%s, method=%s%n", form.attr("action"), form.attr("method"));
    for (Element input : form.select("input,select,textarea")) {
        System.out.printf("\tInput found: name=%s, value=%s%n", input.attr("name"), input.attr("value"));
    }
}
```

This prints currently

```
Form found: action=, method=
    Input found: name=hl, value=en
    Input found: name=source, value=hp
    Input found: name=ie, value=ISO-8859-1
    Input found: name=q, value=
    Input found: name=btnG, value=Google Search
    Input found: name=btnI, value=I'm Feeling Lucky
    Input found: name=, value=
Form found: action=/search, method=
    Input found: name=hl, value=en
    Input found: name=source, value=hp
    Input found: name=ie, value=ISO-8859-1
    Input found: name=q, value=
    Input found: name=btnG, value=Google Search
    Input found: name=btnI, value=I'm Feeling Lucky
```

---

If you want to scan the JSP **source code** for any forms/inputs, then you have to look in a different direction, it's definitely not to be called "web crawler". Unfortunately no such static analysis tool comes to mind. Closest what you can get is to create a `Filter` which logs all submitted request parameters.

```
Map<String, String[]> params = request.getParameterMap();
// ...
```

Comment: Jsoup is in fact a very promising solution. Thank you for your time and for your excellent help!

Comment: You're welcome. Jsoup is indeed awesome. See also [pros and cons of leading Java HTML parsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152138/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-the-leading-java-html-parsers).