# How to get a value from HTML file in Java?

Tags: java, parsing, html-parsing

I need to get a value ("abc" in below example) from HTML file that looks like this:

```
          <input type="hidden" name="something" value="abc" />
```

As i found out from other posts, i should be using one of the HTML parsers (not regex). Could you please tell me which one to use or show a code sample.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org) for this.

```
File file = new File("/path/to/file.html");
Document document = Jsoup.parse(file, "UTF-8");
Element something = document.select("input[name=something]").first();
String value = something.val();
System.out.println(value); // abc
// ...
```

Or shorter:

```
String value = Jsoup.parse(new File("/path/to/file.html"), "UTF-8").select("input[name=something]").first().val();
System.out.println(value); // abc
// ...
```

#### See also:

- [What are the pros and cons of leading Java HTML parsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152138/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-the-leading-java-html-parsers)

Comment: Tnx for quick and accurate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/