# Parsing HTML using java for getting Images(Background:url)

Tags: java

To parse the HTML to get the images I used jsoup..But by using Jsoup if I parsed www.google.com it is showing zero images. In google HTML page images are in form "background:url(/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo1w.png" . I want to get the list of all images from HTML. How can i do this..please help..
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Don't flag for mod attention because you want help.  Its an abuse of the system.  If you cannot find any answers, you will be able to place a bounty on the question in a couple days.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are in a right way. You should just to take the value from html.

Here is @BalusC [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595770/how-to-get-a-value-from-html-file-in-java/4595824#4595824)

```
Element something = document.select("input[name=something]").first();
String value = something.val();
```

Comment: This Didn't worked for me..Is there ant generic way to do this..?