# What is the best way to parse a HTML in a High volume environment?

Tags: java

My application has to be build in java and it has to handle all the java scripts etc...
example
`<html>
.
.
.
<input name=button onclick="javaScript">
.
.
.</html>`

so when i click i should go to the page that the javascript may be calling

This is just a scenario.I do not want to add dynamics (that is click etc) in beginning phase. As a beginning, I want to parse the HTML and want best solution which will handle high volume in the same time be quick and efficient.

It would be helpful if you say the tutorial or book i can refer to build this kind of application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JSoup](http://jsoup.org/)  is the one you are looking for .

**Also See**

- [what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-the-leading-java-html-parsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152138/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-the-leading-java-html-parsers)

Comment: Can you please tell were i can find tutorial or book for this

Comment: But this is a open source which i cannot use

Comment: people are open source freak and you are telling ... may I know the reason aasha ?

Comment: So your org wants to get paid software to parse is it ?