# TagSoup vs. Jsoup vs. HTML Parser vs. HotSax vs

Tags: java, android, html-parsing

The abundance of HTML parsers to choose from (and stick with) is mind boggling:

http://java-source.net/open-source/html-parsers

How do I choose one that best suits the following requirements:

1. Mature (fewer bugs than the rest)
2. Live and breathing (i.e. being
   maintained)
3. Fast and resource-efficient
   (intended to run on Android)

Based on your experience, which HTML parser would you recommend (for meeting the above requirements) and why?

Comment: @George Bailey Thanks. This is a great resource. You correctly understood that I am looking for the *optimal* solution for Android. i.e. Jsoup may be great on a desktop/server but perhaps a different package would be better for a mobile phone.

Comment: Update: Thanks to @George Bailey's link I found another resource: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152138/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-the-leading-java-html-parsers

Comment: Did you find any proper html parser optimal for Android? I am currently using JSoup. Works great but I want to know if it can be optimized futher.

Comment: @Enigma AFAIAC Jsoup is the best. It's possible that I am not aware of something that's better, but project productivity dictates that I cannot constantly switch from one library to another... :)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Well, I found the answer, which was given by @BalusC on a [different thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152138/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-the-leading-java-html-parsers/3154281#3154281):

1. If you just want to use a XML based
   tool to traverse it: [JTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/).
2. If you like to unit test the HTML:
   [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/)
3. If you like to extract specific data
   from the HTML: [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/)

Thank you @BalusC.