# JTidy or Jsoup for Java

Tags: java, screen-scraping, web-scraping, web-crawler

Recently I have been developing web scrapers in python with BeautifulSoup. Now I want to know which libraries are most preferred in Java. I have done some search, mostly I see JTidy and JSoup. What is the difference between them?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183748/tagsoup-vs-jsoup-vs-html-parser-vs-hotsax-vs

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`JTidy` is more commonly used to *tidy* the HTML, that is, to *fix* malformed or faulty HTML, such as unclosed tags, e.g., from `<div><span>text</div>` to `<div><span>text</span></div`.

`JSoup`, on the other hand, provides a full-blown API to parse HTML **and** to *extract* parts of it. It allows you to use jQuery like [selectors](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) to find elements, or [`DOM` methods](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/dom-navigation), equivalent to the ones you use with JavaScript, such as `getElementById`. I'd say JSoup is indeed the BeautifulSoup equivalent of Java.

For example, to extract the first paragraph of a Wikipedia article with JSoup, you could use the following:

```
String url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potato";
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Elements paragraphs = doc.select(".mw-content-ltr p");
String firstParagraph = paragraphs.first().text();
```

Or to extract the title from this very own question:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12439078/jtidy-or-jsoup-for-java").get();
String question = doc.select("#question-header a").text(); // JTidy or Jsoup for Java
```

Quite a nice API, eh? :-)