# JAVA: HTML to XHTML Converter

Tags: java, html, xhtml, converters

I am looking for an effective HTML to XHTML library in Java. I have tried HTML Tidy but it causes this error:

```
XML Parsing Error: mismatched tag. Expected: </meta>.
```

Do you recommend any better library?

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Any particular reason for using XHTML?

Comment: i want to creat a PDF document from html file but the library that i use converts the XHTML to pdf not the normal html .

Comment: you can know more about XHTML from here 

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_xhtml.asp

Comment: I think I know enough about XHTML, thanks ,-) Besides, have a look at [w3fools](http://w3fools.com).

Answer (score 4):

what do you mean by "accurate" results? html is not valid legal xml so making it into xml will obviously change it. have you tried [tagsoup](http://ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/) ? i've used it before to xml-ize html.

also, you might want to look at a few [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183748/tagsoup-vs-jsoup-vs-html-parser-vs-hotsax-vs) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152138/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-the-leading-java-html-parsers/3154281#3154281) that have been asked here before

Comment: Sorry, i meant it gives me this error: XML Parsing Error: mismatched tag. Expected: </meta>.

Comment: +1 for tagsoupn which is exactly the answer to the question, even if the question is ambiguous...

Comment: sorry but i want to convert an HTML file not a web page is the "tagsoup" compatible with that ??

Comment: @mohammad - yes. just use the event stream you get from tagsoup to generate your own xhtml.