# Java API for web scraping or web mining

Tags: java, api, screen-scraping, web-mining

I'm looking for a good Java api to do web scraping.  I tried WEB-Harvest api 
http://web-harvest.sourceforge.net/usage.php but I think it's a bit clunky. 
Any other suggestions?

Comment: "Any other suggestions?" Just one.  Note that when searching for info. on this topic, that word is 'scraping' (one 'p'), not 'scrapping' (which is a separate word that means 'fighting' or 'dumping').

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to "scan" a website (or page) for info, and bring it into my program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835505/how-to-scan-a-website-or-page-for-info-and-bring-it-into-my-program). See also this [recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240981/how-to-easily-parse-html-for-consumption-as-a-service-using-java) for another example. Note that you're basically asking "What is the best HTML parser in Java?".

Comment: you can follow [Web scraping with Java][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202305/web-scraping-with-java

Comment: Comparing libraries is generally off-topic here. See the [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I've used httpunit to do just this task in production.

Answer (score 0):

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/

(Maven Dependency)

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId> 
  <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId> 
  <version>3.1</version> 
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this: https://github.com/subes/invesdwin-webproxy

It supports HttpClient and HtmlUnit (headless browser that supports javascript) and parallelizes it if required over a large pool of proxies. I can also recommend JSoup for static html processing.