# Execute arbitrary JS programmatically on a page

Tags: java, javascript, webforms

I want to programmatically open a web page, execute some JS to fill out and submit a form, then examine the result. What is the best way to do this from Java?

Answer (score 0):

[HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) does all what you want: opening a web page, executing some JS and submitting the form. I'm only not sure how you'd expect to "see" the result. At least, HtmlUnit returns the response in flavor of an `InputStream`.

#### See also:

- [What are the pros and cons of the leading Java HTML parsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152138/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-the-leading-java-html-parsers)

---

**Update**: if you're *actually* looking for automated webpage testing, you may find [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need Cocoon WebTest

http://cocoon.apache.org/