# Convert Html String content to java Map

Tags: java, html, mule

I have the following html string content and i want to convert it into java map using java.

```
<div dir="ltr"><div class="gmail_quote"><div dir="ltr"><div><div dir="ltr"><div><p style="font-family:arial,sans-serif;font-size:13px">Notification for shipment event group &quot;Picked up&quot; for 13 May 14.<u></u><u></u></p>
<div class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="font-family:arial,sans-serif;font-size:13px;text-align:center">
<hr size="2" width="100%" align="center"></div><table border="0" cellpadding="0" style="font-family:arial,sans-serif;font-size:13px">
<tbody><tr><td style="padding:0.75pt">
<p class="MsoNormal">
AWB Number: <a href="http://www.dhl.com/content/g0/en/express/tracking.shtml?brand=DHL&amp;AWB=8841965182" target="_blank">8841965182</a><br>
Pickup Date: 2014-05-13 20:11:00<br>
Service: P<br>
Pieces: 1<br>
enter code here`
```

I have used jsoup but did not worked.

Comment: what do you mean by java map? what do you want to be into the map.

Comment: "did not worked [sic]" is not very helpful. What did not work? What is expected?

Comment: Hi ,  I want the table column name and value to in Map and it should apply to total string example Pickup Date: 2014-05-13 20:11:00 one of MAP value

Comment: Why not just create a Map and put key and values by extracting from html

Comment: just looking the way to extract the html content and setting as map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Boilerpipe](https://code.google.com/p/boilerpipe/?utm_source=rss&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=boilerpipe-boilerplate-removal-and-fulltext-extraction-from-html-pages)

A similar question is asked [here at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7021260/how-can-i-extract-only-the-main-textual-content-from-an-html-page)