# Specific Java HTML parser

Tags: java, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the pros and cons of the leading Java HTML parsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152138/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-the-leading-java-html-parsers)

What HTML parser would you recommend for parsing HTML? 
I need one feature html parser to have:
That parser returns useful text, no menu, no footer, no headers information. Only text that contains normal content.

I have tried Jericho Html parser, HtmlCleaner but they do not seem to work as I need.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure what you're asking; an HTML parser parses HTML--what you extract out of it is up to you. I like [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) and [tagsoup](http://home.ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/).

If you want something that pulls "normal" content out of HTML, you could look at how [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/) handles HTML. All HTML is written differently--you have to be able to define what "normal" content is, and *where* it is.

Comment: I have found incredible parser, exactly what I was looking for. 
You can check it your self its open source: http://boilerpipe-web.appspot.com/

Comment: @Paulius That looks pretty cool; similar to what Tika does. Thanks for the reference.