# Anything better than JSoup for Android?

Tags: android, html, html-parsing, jsoup

What I want to do...

I have a webview in my android app. I get a huge html content from the server as a string and a search string from the application user(the android phone user). Now I break the search string and create a regex out of it. I want all the html content that matches my regex to be highlighted when I display it into my WebView.

What I tried...

Since it is html, I just want to wrap the regex matched words into a pair of   tags with yellow background.

1. Simple regex and replaceAll on the html Content that i get. Very wrong because it screws and replaces even what is inside the '<' and '>'.
2. I tried using Matcher and Pattern combo. It is difficult to omit what is inside the tags.
3. I used JSOUP Parser and it worked!

I traverse the html using NodeTraversor class. I used Matcher and Pattern classes to find and replace matched words with  tags as i wanted to do.

But it is very slow. And I basically want to use it on Android and the size of it is like 284kB. I removed some unwanted classes and it is now 201kB but it is still too much for an android device. Additionally, the html content can be really large. I looked into JSoup source as well. It kind of iterates over every single character when it parses. I do not know whether all the parsers do the same but it is definitely slow for large html documents.

Here is my code -

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Highlighter {

    private String regex;
    private String htmlContent;
    Pattern pat;
    Matcher mat;


    public Highlighter(String searchString, String htmlString) {
        regex = buildRegexFromQuery(searchString);
        htmlContent = htmlString;
        pat = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    }

    public String getHighlightedHtml() {

        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlContent);

        final List<TextNode> nodesToChange = new ArrayList<TextNode>();

        NodeTraversor nd  = new NodeTraversor(new NodeVisitor() {

            @Override
            public void tail(Node node, int depth) {
                if (node instanceof TextNode) {
                    TextNode textNode = (TextNode) node;
                    String text = textNode.getWholeText();

                    mat = pat.matcher(text);

                    if(mat.find()) {
                        nodesToChange.add(textNode);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void head(Node node, int depth) {        
            }
        });

        nd.traverse(doc.body());

        for (TextNode textNode : nodesToChange) {
            Node newNode = buildElementForText(textNode);
            textNode.replaceWith(newNode);
        }
        return doc.toString();
    }

    private static String buildRegexFromQuery(String queryString) {
        String regex = "";
        String queryToConvert = queryString;

        /* Clean up query */

        queryToConvert = queryToConvert.replaceAll("[\\p{Punct}]*", " ");
        queryToConvert = queryToConvert.replaceAll("[\\s]*", " ");

        String[] regexArray = queryString.split(" ");

        regex = "(";
        for(int i = 0; i < regexArray.length - 1; i++) {
            String item = regexArray[i];
            regex += "(\\b)" + item + "(\\b)|";
        }

        regex += "(\\b)" + regexArray[regexArray.length - 1] + "[a-zA-Z0-9]*?(\\b))";
        return regex;
    }

    private Node buildElementForText(TextNode textNode) {
        String text = textNode.getWholeText().trim();

        ArrayList<MatchedWord> matchedWordSet = new ArrayList<MatchedWord>();

        mat = pat.matcher(text);

        while(mat.find()) {
            matchedWordSet.add(new MatchedWord(mat.start(), mat.end()));
        }

        StringBuffer newText = new StringBuffer(text);

        for(int i = matchedWordSet.size() - 1; i >= 0; i-- ) {
            String wordToReplace = newText.substring(matchedWordSet.get(i).start, matchedWordSet.get(i).end);
            wordToReplace = "<b>" + wordToReplace+ "</b>";
            newText = newText.replace(matchedWordSet.get(i).start, matchedWordSet.get(i).end, wordToReplace);       
        }
        return new DataNode(newText.toString(), textNode.baseUri());
    }

    class MatchedWord {
        public int start;
        public int end;

        public MatchedWord(int start, int end) {
            this.start = start;
            this.end = end;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how I call it -

```
htmlString = getHtmlFromServer();
Highlighter hl = new Highlighter("Hello World!", htmlString);
new htmlString = hl.getHighlightedHTML();
```

I am sure what i'm doing is not the most optimal way. But I can't seem to think of anything else.

I want to 
- reduce the time it takes to highlight it. 
- reduce the size of library

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about highlighting them using javascript?

You know, everybody love javascript, and you can find example like [this blog](http://eriwen.com/javascript/highlight-search-results-with-js/).

Comment: they do but i do not want to enable javascript on my webview.

Answer (score 0):

JTidy and HTMLCleaner are aloso among the best Java HTML Parser.

see
[Comparison between different Java HTML Parser](http://www.benmccann.com/blog/java-html-parsing-library-comparison/)

and

[What are the pros and cons of the leading Java HTML parsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152138/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-the-leading-java-html-parsers)

Comment: can we traverse the DOM Tree with JTidy or HTML Cleaner? Any code snippets or link doing that?