# getting links from html source code

Tags: java, html

I have a string as html source code. I want to get only the links from that string and put these links into an ArrayList. As you know, I want to get some strings between `<a href="THE LINK I WANT">`But I want to do this without using any external libraries. How can I do it with simple algorithm using String classes and loops? Thank you!

Comment: Why would you not want to use a HTML parsing library for this? Doing this properly without a library will be reinventing a hugely complicated wheel.

Comment: Because it is an assignment and my instructor want me to do this with simple algorithm. Is it simple?

Comment: It is not that complicated, you can search through the html for `<a` and then skip the characters before you encounter the `href` (or `>` in which case there is no `href` and you have to again start looking for the `<a`) and then from there you store the characters after the `"` to the next `"` and that will be "THE_LINK_YOU_WANT".

Comment: @aphex: No, it isn't simple. HTML parsing isn't trivial. Any "simple" solution will break with non-trivial input such as `<a title='href="' class='"'>`.

Comment: @RoToRa actually it was simple. I found the answer. Even so, thanks for your effort

Comment: No, it's not simple as the commenters above say. It might be simple to parse a small subset of HTML for an assignment, but it certainly isn't to do anything even slightly more complicated (see the example @RoToRa put up).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer!!!!!

```
public ArrayList<String> getLinks() {

    String link = "";

    for(int i = 0; i<url.length()-6; i++) {
        if(url.charAt(i) == 'h' && url.charAt(i+1) == 'r') {
            for(int k = i; k<url.length();k++ ){
                if(url.charAt(k) == '>'){
                    link = url.substring(i+6,k-1);
                    links.add(link);
                    // Break the loop 
                    k = url.length();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return links;
```

Answer (score 5):

`Java Regex API` is not a proper tool to achieve your goal. Use efficient, secure and well tested high-level tools mentioned in the other answers.

If your question concerns rather Regex API than a real-life problem (learning purposes for example) - you can do it with the following code:

```
String html = "foo <a href='link1'>bar</a> baz <a href='link2'>qux</a> foo";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<a href='(.*?)'>");
Matcher m = p.matcher(html);
while(m.find()) {
   System.out.println(m.group(0));
   System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

And the output is:

```
<a href='link1'>
link1
<a href='link2'>
link2
```

Please note that lazy/reluctant qualifier *? must be used in order to reduce the grouping to the single tag. Group 0 is the entire match, group 1 is the next group match (next pair of parenthesis).

---

**A NOTE to Consider :**

Using regular expressions to pull values from HTML is always a mistake. HTML syntax is a lot more complex that it may first appear and it's very easy for a page to catch out even a very complex regular expression.

Use an [HTML Parser](http://www.google.co.uk/search?&q=java%20html%20parser) instead. See also [What are the pros and cons of the leading Java HTML parsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152138/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-the-leading-java-html-parsers)

Comment: As I stated my question, I don't want to use any external libraries. I found the answer. Even so, thanks for your answer

Comment: your method, as u stated in your answer, is just a workaround..not a proper method..!!..You can at least use "regex" to solve your problem..!! (and its not an external library)

Comment: Actually It is not necessarily proper, because I want you just a simple algorithm. I've solved though :D

Comment: Its your call..!!...but if you would show my answer to your instructor, he would be definitely surprised and happy..!!.. ;)