# android how to get src value from image tag

Tags: android, html

In Android, I want to get value from src attribute from image tag as follow.

```
<img border="0" height="430" src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-551kBiFcc3o/US2MxmAHq1I/AAAAAAAAZvM/DjurUt5-4Ac/s640/856738_537952452911181_897510449_o.jpg" width="640">
```

Comment: you can search for src= in the link and after that take the whole string until the next " . that should do the trick.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing Html in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9664778/parsing-html-in-java)

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [regular expressions](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) to filter out img src's:

```
String imgRegex = "<img[^>]+src\\s*=\\s*['\"]([^'\"]+)['\"][^>]*>";
```

You should use this only if [you know what you're doing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) (as CommonsWare noted in the comments)

The rest is up to you - you've given us a little information about the context.

Comment: How to get content from <meta name="twitter-redirect-srcs" content="{&quot;pwreset-iphone&quot;:true,&quot;android&quot;:true,&quot;email&quot;:true}"/> this html tag . Please help me. @Tool