# Displaying the length of a word using dashes

Tags: java

So I get a random word from a website and use the `length()` method to obtain how many letters are in the word.  Now I want to display these as dashes (`-`).  For example, say the word is "dogs".  The length method will return 4.  Now I want to convert that into `----`.  Is there any way in java to say in `-` the number representing the length of the word?

Comment: You can loop `length` times and append or print a '-'.

Comment: you have to parse the html in java and search check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9664778/parsing-html-in-java?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 9):

The simplest would probably be to use a regex:

```
String dashes = input.replaceAll(".", "-");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
    str.append("-");
}
System.out.println(str.toString());
```