# Way to turn this poorly formed HTML into well-formed XHTML?

Tags: html, parsing, jsoup

I'm using JSoup 1.6.2.  I have this HTML ...

```
 <a title="Subscribe to RSS feeds" href="http://domain/city/RSS" style="float:right; margin-left:10px;"">
```

Notice the stray quote right before the end of the tag.  I was hoping JSoup could clean that up somehow.  I try and make everything right by running ...

```
final org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
```

The result is

```
  <a title="Subscribe to RSS feeds" href="http://domain/city/RSS" style="float:right; margin-left:10px;" "="">
```

which is still not well-formed.  Is there a way I can take the badly formed HTMl and make it well-formed with JSoup?  Barring that, is there another HTML tidy-upper that can do the job for the above example but also allow me to access the resulting HTML as either a String or a org.w3c.dom.Document object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3154281/432836) answer, I will recommend you to use JTidy for "tidy" the HTML source.

Comment: Thanks.  JTidy works in my situation.  I was looking at their web site, the last release seems to be from 2007.  Does that mean the project has died?

Answer (score 0):

Can you just use a regular expression replace to fix this? I'm not sure how to do it in Java, but in JavaScript it would be something like this:

```
var str = '<a title="Subscribe to RSS feeds" href="http://domain/city/RSS" style="float:right; margin-left:10px;"">';

var newStr = str.replace(/""/,'"');
//<a title="Subscribe to RSS feeds" href="http://domain/city/RSS" style="float:right; margin-left:10px;">
```