# Android and Jsoup

Tags: android, webview, jsoup

I'm trying to bring a part of the contents of a website. I decided to use the Jsoup because with it I can take the part of the site you want and play the html part of this withdrawal within a webview. It seemed easy, but I tried to run my application and did not work. Below is my code. What's wrong with him?

Note: If there is another simpler way to do this, pass me the hint! But I want to get the contents in real time, ok?
Thanks to all!

> public class RestauranteUniversitarioActivity extends Activity {
>
> ```
> @Override
> public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.main);
>     WebView cardapio = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.web_engine);
>     
>     cardapio.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
>     
>     String data = "";
>     
>     Document doc = null;
>     try {
>     doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.iguatu.ce.gov.br/").get();
>     }
>   catch (IOException e) {
>     e.printStackTrace();
>   }
>     
>     Elements content = doc.getElementsByClass("dest-left");
>     if(content.size() > 0) {
>       data = content.get(1).text();
>     }
>           cardapio.loadData(data, "text/html", "UTF-8");
> }
> ```
>
> }

Answer (score 2):

The problem is most likely that you're parsing the webpage in the main (UI) Thread. This will lock up the UI/cause your app to freeze. Move the `doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.iguatu.ce.gov.br/").get();` to a background thread, for example by using an `AsyncTask` or `(Intent)Service`.

Answer (score 1):

Refer [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152138/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-the-leading-java-html-parsers/3154281#3154281) if you are looking for an alternative html parser.

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class HtmlParserActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        WebView cardapio = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_engine);
        cardapio.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        String data = "";
        Document doc = null;
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10695350/androi-and-jsoup").get();
            Elements elements = doc.getElementsByClass("post-tag");
            for(Element element : elements) {
                data += element.outerHtml();
                data += "<br/>";
            }
            cardapio.loadData(data, "text/html", "UTF-8");
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } 
}
```

Reference [Jsoup Cookbook](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/)

Comment: From Alessandro Forcuti: Please check url in Jsoup.connect(...) and replace "androi-" with "android-"

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I do not have enough reputation for comment under answer of Dira.
Please check url in Jsoup.connect(...) and replace "androi-" with "android-"