# How do i get specifics from html?

Tags: java, html, urlconnection

I have some java code that will print out html from a website of my choosing.  I would like it to only print out specific dates in HTML code that looks like this:

```
<tr class="bgWhite">
  <td align="center" width="50"><nobr>GD&#160;</nobr></td>
  <td align="center">Q3&#160;2012</td>

  <td align="left" width="*">Q3 2012 General Dynamics Earnings Release</td>
  <td align="center">$ 1.83&#160;</td>
  <td align="center">n/a&#160;</td>
  <td align="center">$ 1.83&#160;</td>
  <td align="center"><nobr>24-Oct-12</nobr></td>
</tr>
<tr class="bgWhite">
  <td align="center" width="50"><nobr>GD&#160;</nobr></td>
  <td align="center">Q2&#160;2012</td>

  <td align="left" width="*">Q2 2012 General Dynamics Earnings Release</td>
  <td align="center">$ 1.75&#160;</td>
  <td align="center">n/a&#160;</td>
  <td align="center">$ 1.79&#160;</td>
  <td align="center"><nobr>25-Jul-12 BMO</nobr></td>
</tr>
```

So I only want it to print out:
    24-Oct-12
    25-Jul-12

How do I do that?

Here is the code that I have:

```
String nextLine;
URL url = null;
URLConnection urlConn = null;
InputStreamReader  inStream = null;
BufferedReader buff = null;

try{
    // Create the URL obect that points
    // at the default file index.html
    url  = new URL("http://www.earnings.com/company.asp?client=cb&ticker=gd");
    urlConn = url.openConnection();
    inStream = new InputStreamReader( 
                       urlConn.getInputStream());
    buff= new BufferedReader(inStream);

    // Read and print the lines from index.html
    while (true){
        nextLine =buff.readLine();  
        if (nextLine !=null){
            System.out.println(nextLine); 
        }
        else{
           break;
        } 
    }
 } catch(MalformedURLException e){
   System.out.println("Please check the URL:" + 
                                       e.toString() );
 } catch(IOException  e1){
  System.out.println("Can't read  from the Internet: "+ 
                                      e1.toString() ); 
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason you cannot use an XML parser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easier to use a fullworthy HTML parser for the job than low level `java.net.URLConnection`. However, since the targeted website generates absolutely non-semantic HTML (one and all tables without any semantic identifiers/classes, like as how the average 90's website looked (yuck)), it's even for a decent HTML parser tricky to parse it properly. But anyway, here's a complete kickoff example using [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org) which prints exactly the information you need:

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://www.earnings.com/company.asp?client=cb&ticker=gd").get();
Elements dateColumn = document.select("table:eq(0) tr:eq(0) table:eq(7) tr:eq(2) table:eq(4) td:eq(6):not(.dataHdrText02)");

for (Element dateCell : dateColumn) {
    System.out.println(dateCell.text());
}
```

That's all. No need to hassle with low level `java.net.URLConnection` or a verbose SAX parser.

#### See also:

- [What are the pros and cons of the leading Java HTML parsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152138/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-the-leading-java-html-parsers)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a standard UC for a SAX parser. You shouldn't go line by line (you can't expect the html document to be always organized as it currently is, so using a SAX parser would be a more flexible solution).

If you have information about the size of the document and you know it will not grow very much you can also use a DOM parser. But the SAX parser is better from this point of view,too.