# Java regular expression to extract key value pairs

Tags: java, regex

How can I extract the value of the `bookid` from this string using Java?

```
href="http://www.books.com/?bookname=cooking&bookid=12345678&bookprice=123.45">cooking book
```

Comment: Tried Pshemo's solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally you should use some parser but if your String is really this short then maybe regular expression can be option like

```
String s="href=\"http://www.books.com/?bookname=cooking&bookid=12345678&bookprice=123.45\">cooking book";
Pattern p= Pattern.compile("(?<=bookid=)\\d+");
Matcher m=p.matcher(s);
if (m.find())
    System.out.println(m.group());
```

output:

> 12345678

Comment: Thanks Pshemo, Actually the String is the full HTML source of a page where this is just a part where the bookid is present, so I guess I can use your solution for that as well?

Comment: Actually regular expressions are considered as [bad practice](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1393766) for parsing HTML. For example my solution will find number that is preceded by "bookid=" so if your HTML will contain that combination before your href (for example in some comment or other content generated by user) you can have bad results. For parsing entire HTML code use special tools designed for that. Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152138/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-the-leading-java-html-parsers) will help you a little.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple answer would be

```
String[] queryParams =  url.split("\\?")[1].split("&");
```

This would give you all the parameters in a=b form in each of the element. You can then just split the needed param.

But ideally you should extract the value by **param name**

Answer (score 0):

Pshemo you beat me to it but you can also use this:
    "(id\=[0-9]*)"

and try [RegexPlanet](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) to try out your regex and retrieve the escapped string in java format

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code snippet:

```
            String str = "href=\"http://www.books.com/?bookname=cooking&bookid=12345678&bookprice=123.45\">cooking book";
            String[] strArray = str.split("&");
            String bookId = "";
            for(int i=0;i<strArray.length;i++)
            {
               if(strArray[i].startsWith("bookid"))
               {
                  bookId = strArray[i].split("=")[1];
               }
            }
            System.out.println("Book ID = "+bookId);
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use `strArray[i].split("=", 1)[1]` instead of `strArray[i].split("=")[1]`?