# Getting DOM of webpage with Java

Tags: java, dom

I am making a new browser and I need to get the DOM of a webpage to do it. How do I do this?

Comment: `HTML (text markup) -> "HTML Parser" -> DOM (structure/API)`. However, you'll likely need more than "the DOM" for anything not absolutely trivial .. consider integration with (e.g. using) existing browser engines.

Comment: Discussion of the various Java HTML parsers: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3152138/209103

Comment: If you've ever heard of google gravity this browser is meant to create a whole browser just like that.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to write an HTML parser or use an existing one such as http://jsoup.org/