# How to extract HTML tags to get only certain information?

Tags: java, html, string, extract

I need to extract the webpage's title from between the `<title> </title>` tags.

Also need to display all of the text located between the `<body...>` and `</body>` tags but nothing outside the body.

I don't want any angle brackets or any of the html data returned.

Comment: If the course you're in is reasonably structured, then you should have the basic tools to approach this. If it isn't, then all due respect to the instructor, this is all kinds of nuts. For one thing, *"Display all of the text located between the `<body...>` and `</body>` tags and nothing outside the body`"* So, then, not like a real web browser, which is rather smarter than that.

Comment: yeah, I'm getting this assignment during our chapter over Streams. So I'm thinking he really just wants to make sure we know how to manipulate input streams. It being HTML is what is confusing me because after looking at lots of HTML they seem to vary quite a bit.

Comment: Check [JTidy library](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/). It saved me a lot of time for HTML parsing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
String html = "<html>My page</html>";
String title = html.substring(html.indexOf("<html>") + 6, html.indexOf("</html"));
System.out.println(title);
```

The [String.indexOf(string)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int%29) method returns the start index of a string (in the example, `"<html>"` and `"</html>"`) in the given string (the variable html).

The [String.substring(int, int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) method returns the string between 2 indexes.

With this, you can start your browser.

Comment: Oh, so .indexOf returns the location index of the first character of the given string in the file?

Comment: Also, with your `+6`  was that just an arbitrary number or is that something of value?

Comment: @GabrielleLee: It's the number of characters in `<html>`, so that the `substring` starts with the first character *after* the opening tag.

Comment: It gives you the position of the first character of the string. The +6 is because the word <html> has 6 characters length.

Comment: Oh, ok thanks. I looked at the API for `indexOf` and it says i have to put in a char. So will it just look for the first char of the string i put in? Like would your code just find the first instance of `"<"`

Comment: Or does it really search for the whole string given?

Comment: It can look for a String as well, as in the example.

Answer (score 1):

> To simplify my question, how do I search through a giant string to find another string and record its location?

[`String#indexOf(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String%29) For instance:

```
int index = bigString.indexOf("<body");
```

...finds the first occurence of `<body` in `bigString` and returns its index (which you could use with `substring`). But if you're not sure how to do that, the assignment is nuts. The course should have properly prepared you for this task, and it seems like it hasn't.

Parsing HTML is *complicated*. You can do a half-complete, incorrect job using `indexOf` and `substring`, but it will be...half-complete and incorrect.

Comment: Thanks this really clears things up.

Answer (score 1):

There are lot of ways to approach this problem but using the constraints you have presented lets take a low level approach.  First assuming you have received this entire HTML document into a string called `html`.  The first task will be to search for ''.  There is a lot of error checking that this answer will not cover, but then we can't do all of your homework for you :P, so we will assume that the `title` elements are in lowercase and well formed:

First we need to determin where in the HTML is the title element (here I am using [`indexOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String,%20int%29))

```
int start = html.indexOf("<title>")+"<title>".length();
int end = html.indexOf("</title>", start);
```

Then to extract it into a string (using [`substring()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29)):

```
String title = html.substring(start, end);
```

Answer (score 0):

From your description you don't need to parse the complete HTML documen't, but only extract some information from it. An approach based on a [Finite State Machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) will work.

Scan until you find a `<title>` element. From that point anything is data, until you find a closing `</title>`. Then scan until you find an opening `<body>`. From that point you will need to read the "content" skipping anything that is between `<` and `>`, which may be done as follow:

```
//input stream in is just after <body>
String body=""; 
String element="";
boolean ignore=false
while (true) {
  char c = in.read();
  if (c<0) break; //end of stream
  if (ignore) {
    if (c=='>') {
      if (element.equals("/body")) break; //closing </body>
      ignore=false;
    }
    else element+=c;
  }  else {
    //not in ignore mode
    if (c=='<') {element=""; ignore=true;}
    else body+=c;
  }
```

Comment: I am a very brand new programmer and I don't know what a "finite State Machine" is. Plus my instructions detail that I should read in the whole HTML and then search through and cut it up.

Comment: Basically a FSM means that you begin analyzing the string in some "state", and you switch states depending on your input. In this case one state would be "data" and other state would be "tag". If you are reading *data*, you append the read character. If you are reading a *tag*, you verify whether it was the closing body.

I wrote an example reading on the fly from the stream. You may do the same saving the string into a `String`, the scanning the string with `charAt` within a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

There are two developmental phases programmers use to solve these sorts of problems:

**1.  Parse out the data yourself:**

In HTML (good HTML) most tags are followed by closing tags. A `<title>` tag is one of them. If you're trying to find what is in between them, find the index of `<title>`. You probably want the index of the last `>` just for ease.

Then while current character is not `<`, add that character to a string.

When you hit a `<`, you should check if it's `</title>`. If not, continue reading. Essentially you keep looping. Each time you hit a `<` check if it's a closing title tag.

When you realize that this is super hard and re-inventing the wheel, advance to step 2:

**2.  Use a DOM parser library.**

After you have hurt yourself trying to do step 1.  You discover why programmers strongly advise you never parse HTML or use regex on HTML.  Realize the battle has already been fought and won with battletested HTML parsers: [What are the pros and cons of the leading Java HTML parsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152138/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-the-leading-java-html-parsers)

Comment: *"In HTML (good HTML) all tags are followed by closing tags..."* You mean like `<br>` and `<input type="text">`?

Comment: Point made. The original sentence is incorrect, but the rest of it is still fine. I shall edit now :)

Comment: Ok, so I think I am getting what you are saying. Let me try and rephrase it to see if i get it :

Comment: I should search through character by character until I hit a `<`

Comment: then i need to see if there is a t, then an i, then a t, then a l, then an e after that first `>`

Comment: If so, then add all of the characters after the index of the `>` until I reach a `<` followed by the rest of the ending tag?

Comment: Is there a way to search for whole phrases or do I really have to search with a giant loop for the sequential characters < T I T L E > ?

Comment: Check out Igor's answer. He's explained the concept better :)

Comment: @ChrisCooney: *"Please ignore the spaces at the start of the title tags. It's just so they aren't interpreted as HTML by stack overflow :)"* To the right when you were typing your answer, there was this handy **How to Format** box. Worth a read. I've fixed this one for you, but as you've posted 38 answers and 4 questions as of this writing, it's surprising that I should need to.

Comment: I confess, I don't answer many HTML questions. Luckily I have my guardian angel!