# How to use indexOf to print out the indexOf range?

Tags: java

1) In my java program it connects to an webpage and grabs the html page source.
2) It then proceeds to turn that entire page source into a string (htmlString).
3) I would like to grab a value inside the html source and place it into a string (myString).
4) I am trying to use indexOf and have the following regex that is able to find the position right before the start of the value I am trying to obtain:

```
System.out.println(htmlString.indexOf("<input name=\"k\" value=\"", 1));
```

This returns 4861

5) I would like to print out the values and store them into a string for the indexOf position range of 4862 - 4893.
And I cannot seem to figure out how to do that.

Also, the value for this indexOf range 4862-4893 changes every time the page is refreshed. Otherwise I would just directly search for that particular value.

Basic example of what I'm trying to do:

HTML source:

```
<input type='hidden' name='k' value='nnhMTGbb2z5eryuksFGns9tt0EEjqBX8'>
```

using regex and indexOf I searched for:

```
<input type='hidden' name='k' value=
```

found it to be in position 4861 and now I need to grab everything from 4862-4893, this value: 
nnhMTGbb2z5eryuksFGns9tt0EEjqBX8
and place it into a string.

I must be missing something simple I feel. What should I do?

Comment: if you already know the values, why not just call [subString(int beginIndex, int endIndex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex's are notoriously bad for parsing HTML.  If I were you I'd use a library meant for parsing html like the ones in this SO question: [What are the pros and cons of the leading Java HTML parsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152138/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-the-leading-java-html-parsers/)  Consider, for example, that the `type` could be changed to be at the end of the tag instead of at the beginning.  The HTML would still be valid, but your regex/indexof would now be useless.  These are probably the kinds of problems you don't want to think about.

But if you insist, you could use the [StringUtils.lastIndexOf](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang///javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#lastIndexOf%28java.lang.String,%20char%29)

Answer (score 1):

Consider to use [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) for parsing html