# Error tolerant java xml parser

Tags: java, xml

I need to parse an xml chunk which I get without root element, namespace delaration and entity declaration despite including all of the three.
So far I've been using `Dom4j` and doing some wrapping around the content but new entites and namespaces keep to appear and the `DTD/Schema` of the content is not accessible.

Given that I don't control the source from which I'm getting XML, 
Is there any kind of `java XML parser` that will tolerate these errors?

1. Abscence of root element
2. Unbound namespaces
3. Undeclared    entities

Comment: The proper solution to your problem would be to contact the source and ask them to comply to standards. Whatever they are giving you sure ain't XML. If TagSoup fails you, you could write your own parser. Check [ANTLR4](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Home) parser generator. It's [reference book](http://pragprog.com/book/tpantlr2/the-definitive-antlr-4-reference) has XML parsing examples.

Comment: XML does not require a namespace declaration.

Comment: But the xml data that I manipulate uses namespaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using [TagSoup](http://ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/) which is "forgiving" many errors in the markup.

To work around absence of the root element you can always add your own root element around the XML chunk that you need to parse.

Comment: Stills the namespace binding and the entities declaration problem.

Comment: TagSoup will simply suppress all the namespaces. It also supports 2000+ entities already.

Comment: TagSoup seems interesting but how to use it? Any tutorials? Moreover does it have querying capability(xPath)?

Comment: there is also another library called jsoup which provides quering capabilities. Also this questions gives some more links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152138/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-the-leading-java-html-parsers/3154281#3154281

Comment: I cannot find TagSoup on ccil.org now, but i found its fork on github: https://github.com/orbeon/tagsoup

Answer (score 0):

I think all major Java XML parsers have these strict requirements such as a root element.
The simple way around all this is to write your own Java XML parser. If you are using the XML purely as a config file then i suggest you look into using Java Properties.

Thanks,
Reece

Comment: Thanks but the xml is used for storing application data.

Comment: Okay in which case try making your own XML parser (The .split() method is your friend if you want it done quick) or change to a a database which can store application files and data much faster than XML.

Comment: They must be strict *to be XML parsers*. If a text does not conform to the definition of XML, it is *not XML*.

Comment: I know but i think they are just using the XML 'format' style, so yes this would work..