# Regexp and custom tags

Tags: java, android, regex

i have a string like this..

```
<mytag>one line</mytag><mytag>second line with other tag <color=red>this words are red</color></mytag><youtube>GY7IU5FU</youtube>
```

How can i get this..

```
1 - (TAG) - mytag
1 - (DATA) - one line
2 - (TAG) - mytag
2 - (DATA) - second line with other tag <color=red>this words is red</color>
3 - (TAG) - youtube
3 - (DATA) - GY7IU5FU
```

Im trying with this but not work

```
<(.*).*?<\/?\1>
```

Comment: Why do you want to use regex? This is html.

Comment: or just use capture groups with your regex. a quick google search for 'java regex capture groups' reveals [this](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/regular_expressions/capturing_groups.shtml#.Us1ymGRDsrg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speaking from a little experience, regular expressions are simply not cut out for heavy-duty parsing. HTML falls into that category.

You need a full-blown parser. Lucky for you, SO has the information you need right [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152138/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-the-leading-java-html-parsers).

Answer (score 0):

As a partial answer to your question which might help you get started, here is some Java:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<[^<>]*?>");
Matcher m = p.matcher("<mytag>foo</mytag>");
if (m.find()){
    String str= m.group(0)
}
```

This snippet captures `mytag` in  `<mytag>foo</mytag>`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Solution in python (re module for regular expressions):

```
re.findall(r"<(mytag|youtube)>(.*?)</\1>",a)

Output: 
[('mytag', 'one line'),
('mytag', 'second line with other tag <color=red>this words are red</color>'),
('youtube', 'GY7IU5FU')]
```

Explanation: This regex matches the start of a mytag or youtube tag, followed by the text inside the tag(in a non-greedy fashion to avoid a situation where
ab would match ab as the text.

If you want to match all top-level tags and contents then use the following regex string:

```
<(.+)>(.*?)</\1>
```