# Easy Way to Add Closing Tags on HTML Document so XSLT can be Applied

Tags: java, html, xml, xslt

I am working on a system where I need to pass some HMTL through an XSLT transformation, but the HTML has a few header tags that don't have closing tags so it is not technically "well-formed" to be able to apply XSLT. Here are the tags:

```
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="smartdoc.css">
```

Here is the issue, the documents that I am working with are downloaded to a server so I don't have direct access to simply open the file, in say notepad, and close the tags manually. What is the best way to go about closing those tags so that I can use the XSLT on them? Note I am using a Java library to run the XSLT transformation so I could potentially use something from Java to edit the HTML before applying the XSLT, but I am not sure what to use.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Java version of [HTML Tidy](http://www.html-tidy.org/) called [**JTidy**](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/) that you could use to clean-up your HTML.

The [JTidy How To Page](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/howto.html) shows an example use of their [API](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/apidocs/index.html):

```
Tidy tidy = new Tidy(); // obtain a new Tidy instance
tidy.setXHTML(boolean xhtml); // set desired config options using tidy setters 
...                           // (equivalent to command line options)

tidy.parse(inputStream, System.out); // run tidy, providing an input and 
                                     // output stream
```

Answer (score 0):

I use [tagsoup](http://home.ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/).
By the way, take a look at this thread : [What are the pros and cons of the leading Java HTML parsers? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152138/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-the-leading-java-html-parsers)